# How to write new subfolders in java?

Tags: java

I'm processing some .xml files by using XSLT.

By doing this

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(
                Paths.get("/myPath/myfile.xsl").toFile()));
        new XsltTransformer(Paths.get("/mypath/source_files"),
                Paths.get("/mypath/target_files"), transformer)
                        .run();
    }
```

I'm able to transform all the .xml files from `source_files` folder and save the resulting files in `target_files`. By adding a subfolder to my `source_file` like `/mypath/source_files/test` I'm having this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mypath/target_files/test/test.xml (No such file or directory)
```

So, the source path and the target path must be the same.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's no class named `XsltTransformer` in the core libraries, nor are there any popular* ones that match what you've written here.

Perhaps this is your XsltTransformer code? It's not clear from context.

Assuming it is your code, you get a No such file or directory error when you attempt to write to a file that doesn't exist (ordinarily, no problem, that would normally just create the file and write to it)... **in a directory that doesn't exist**. I think you know that, but the question lacks detail, so I'm highlighting it here.

Whenever you are writing code that creates a file, and you want the behaviour of: "Create whatever directories you need to, first, then write to it", this is how to do that:

```
public void writeHello(Path p) throws IOException {
    Files.createDirectories(p.getParent());
    Files.write(p, "Hello");
}
```

The important bit being the `createDirectories` line. Note that it will silently do nothing (and doesn't throw anything) if p.getParent exists and is already a directory, which is presumably exactly what you want. So, just add that one liner before you write your xslt stuff.

If XsltTransformer is *not* your own code, there are two options: [1] update your question and explain what library you are using, or [2] do an analysis on your input dir yourself, find all subdirs (recursively, properly), manually make all dirs in the target folder, and then let this XsltTransformer thing at it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe add the subfolder in XsltTransformer path? Like this:

```java
new XsltTransformer(Paths.get("/mypath/source_files/test"),
```